# Is Arrow a dog species?

Tags: dogs

"[Me and My Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_and_My_Arrow)" is a song written and recorded by American singer-songwriter Harry Nilsson for his 1970 album The Point!

The song was composed as the theme for Oblio, the pointless boy, and his dog, Arrow.

According to this, Arrow is just a name of the pet dog of the pointless boy.

Although I saw people talked "my Arrow". Is this a analogy/metaphor or there is a dog species Arrow?

Comment: No, its not a dog breed.  Also, I seriously recommend against googling this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What keywords do you recommend I use to google? I did search "dog arrow", "is Arrow a dog breed", and something like that, none of the results tell me clearly Arrow is not a dog breed.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to clearly tell something absolutely isn't. But looking at lists of common dog breeds might be a start and one can't find arrow in any of them. There'd many more things that are not a dog breed than are.

Comment: @yaojp you're working on a logical fallacy; you cannot prove a negative. However, if it were a dog breed, you WOULD find proof of it, therefore, the likelihood that it's just the dog's name is CONSIDERABLY higher than the likelihood that it's some super-secret hush-hush dog breed only the most privileged know about, yet somehow made it into a song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no (official) dog breed named "Arrow". Have a look at the [list of common dog breeds on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dog_breeds) or another [list of dog breeds by DogTime](https://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/profiles). They do contain different breeds, but none of them contain any "Arrow".

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_and_My_Arrow) you linked to states:

> The song was composed as the theme for Oblio, the pointless boy, and his dog, Arrow.

**Arrow is the name of the dog,** not it's breed.

If you follow the link to the article "[The Point!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Point!)", you can read even more about Arrow.

> Oblio wins [a competition] with the help of his dog Arrow.
>
> A jury reluctantly convicts both Oblio and Arrow
>
> Oblio and Arrow are sent to the Pointless Forest

Since the song "Me and my Arrow" was quite popular for a time, it's very likely that people use similar phrases as metaphors, references or analogies.